# Why doesn't JavaScript allow assigning the property "name" on a Function?

Tags: javascript, properties

See below for what happened in Firefox and Chrome's console:

```
> var f = function() {}
undefined
> f.name = 'f'
"f"
> f.name
""
> f.id = 1
1
> f.id
1
```

Why `f.name = 'f'` is a no-op?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably depends on the implementation.

In some implementations, the `name` property of a function object is used as the function's name if it has one. This is likely read-only in these cases.

This is a non-standard feature.

for example:

```
var foo = function bar() {};

alert(foo.name); // will give "bar" in some cases.
```

---

In Firefox and Chrome, if I try to modify it, it won't change...

```
var foo = function bar() {};

foo.name = "baz";
alert(foo.name); // still "bar" in Firefox and Chrome
```

---

- [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name) for the  `name` property.

Here are some key points from the docs...

> "***Non-standard***"
>
> *"The name property returns the name of a function, or an empty string for anonymous functions"*
>
> *"You cannot change the name of a function, this property is read-only"*